# Домен на ip адрес ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, http, https, порты

Всем привет!

У меня запускается сайт на 42.142.42:8082 Я привязывал свой ip адрес к домену, но порт, как я понял привязать нельзя. И поэтому при переходе по доменному имени я попадаю на 42.142.42 (сайт без порта).

Как мне добиться результата, чтобы я переходил по привязанному домену, и он использовал порт на котором запущен сайт.

Comment: Зависит от того, как у Вас реализовано подключение машины на которой крутится сайт, какой web server Вы используете. К примеру можно спроксировать запросы с <vash_domain>.<zone>:80 (80й порт используется по умолчанию и к адресу не добавляется, хотя и подразумевается) на localhost:8082 (на котором, как я полагаю, и крутится Ваш проект)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свою задачу я решил следующим образом.

Перенаправил с порта 80 на порт 8082

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8082`